# ghooks, where did you come from?

Tags: git

I've been minding my own business, gitting along, and suddenly I'm getting this error anytime I do anything with git:

```
ghooks not found!
Make sure you have it installed on your "node_modules".
Skipping git hooks.
```

Now that I've learned what ghooks are, I didn't realize I was using them. Apparently, they've gone missing.

I'm not going out of my way to use ghooks for anything. As far as I can tell, they've been deprecated anyway. I'm just wondering what I could have done to cause this issue, and what I can do to make it go away. The following command didn't help:

```
npm install -g ghooks
```

Perhaps unrelated, this error showed up about the same time as another error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my_repository'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I pushed some changes, and everything was fine. I made more changes, committed, and pushed those, and all of the sudden, I'm behind the branch I'm working ahead of?

So I went and pulled out gitk for the first time in ages, and it's obvious by the squirrel's nest of local branches that don't always lead to a merge that our workflow went off the tracks somewhere. There are a ton of guides for these things, so I'm going to brush up on those and try to get us back on track. I'm confessing my git sins to you now in case it's related to the ghooks thing. Perhaps this is git's way of telling me that I've been screwing things up for too long.

TIA!

Comment: I strongly suggest reading the first 3 chapters of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). What seems to have happened is that somehow a commit hook that depends on `ghooks` got added, so because `ghooks` isn't present `git` complains.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me when I moved the project directory to another directory. ie. from /user/old/project to /user/new/project

**My fix**
Edit every ghooks file in .git/hooks and replace the old file path, with the new file path